# How can I set the second layer of an NPC visible using PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata in 1_18_R1 (without Mojang Mapping)?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I'm trying to code a Minecraft Spigot Plugin using NMS. I want to create and spawn an NPC. The code I wrote for creating the `EntityPlayer`, `GameProfile` and for sending the packets works fine, but I can't figure out how to set the `EntityPlayer` metadata in 1.18.1. I've tried doing the same thing in 1.15 and it worked perfectly.

`md_5` remapped a lot of methods. For example, to get the `DataWatcher` of an `EntityPlayer`, I used to do `npc.getDataWatcher();`, but now I have to use `npc.ai();`. I can't seem to find a solution on the internet that works in 1.18.1 without any other APIs such as Citizens.

I think I figured out all the methods counterparts, but it still doesn't work.

So, how did the way you set Metadata of an `EntityPlayer` change in 1.18.1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.